# Xlib - focus mode

Tags: xlib, window-managers

I'm writing a simple window manager (using xlib) for school and I have one problem. I really don't like the default X11 focus mode: 'sloppy focus' (the focus follows the mouse pointer) so I want to change that behavior.

I'm overriding the EnterNotify event but I still have sloppy focus. Can someone please show me the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue - if you figure out, I have a [project](http://github.com/adamnew123456/SmallWM) which could really use the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Just use XSetInputFocus() to set the focus to any window, and the sloppy focus disappears.